# Simple tcp server c++ check available bytes

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, tcp

I'm trying to make a simple tcp server according to this [lesson](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm). Everything works fine, and now I'm trying to encapsulate functions in the Socket class. I try to make a method that checks the amount of available bytes to read, and I can't find necessary the function. It could be some kind of `ftell()` or another method.

Comment: You can tell this from the socket. You need a protocol that has size information in-bedded in the protocol. All the server can tell from the connection is that it is open, there are x bytes currently available to read (but x may not be the full length of the message just what has currently arrived (more packets may be on the way (or have been re-requested))).

Comment: What is your outer problem? What would you use this function for? The answer is very different if you just want to log it than it is if you want to wait until a certain number of bytes is available.

Comment: As I said at comment to the post below, I need to check "Am I at the end of file or not?"

Comment: Sockets are not files. You will not know if you are at the end of file or not unless other side tells you, either by closing the socket or by informing you of the file size in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be respecting the communication protocol you are implementing on top of TCP.  It dictates how you should be reading data and how you should be determining the sizes of the data to be read.  If the protocol expects an integer, read an integer.  If the protocol expects a length-preceded string, read the length value and then read how many bytes it specifies.  If the protocol expects a delimited string, read until you encounter the delimiter.  And so on.

That being said, to answer the actual question you asked - "[how to] check the amount of available bytes to read":

- on Windows, you can use the [`ioctlsocket()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573.aspx) function, where the `cmd` parameter is set to `FIONREAD` and the `argp` parameter is set to a pointer to a `u_long` variable.

  ```
  u_long bytesAvailable;
  ioctlsocket(socket, FIONREAD, &bytesAvailable);
  ```
- on *Nix, you can use the [`ioctl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) function, where the `request` parameter is set to `FIONREAD` and the third parameter is set to a pointer to a `int` variable.

  ```
  int bytesAvailable;
  ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &bytesAvailable);
  ```

In either case, the output variable receives the number of unread bytes currently waiting on the socket.  It is guaranteed that you can read *at most* this many bytes from the socket using `recv()` without blocking the calling thread (if the socket is running in a blocking mode).  The socket may receive more bytes between the time you query `FIONREAD` and the time you call `recv()`, so if you try to read more than `FIONREAD` indicates, `recv()` may or may not have to block the calling thread waiting for more bytes.

Answer (score -1):

Can you elaborate on why you would need to know that?

The preferred way to read data from a socket is to first make sure it has data you can read, via a call to `select` and then read into a predefined array, whose size is set to that of maximum size you and the client respect. Read will then report how many bytes it has read.

I might also add you should also `select` a socket before writing data to it.

Finally, you might want to look up circular buffers as they offer a way to append data to a buffer without risking to fill up your RAM. You would then read the data from the circular buffer once you have enough data.

As far as I know, it is not recommended to check how many bytes are available to be read on a socket.

Comment: Well I can rephrase my question, Am I at the end of file or not? The method read() blocks thread until data come and I want to setup some timeout for reading. Simple way to do it is check available bytes to read during timeout period.

Comment: If you are reading from a file you should not use sockets for one.

Also, as I said, when working with sockets you should use `select` wich will block until data is available. If you wish, you can also add a 4th argument to select which is the timeout. If you return from `select` and none of you fds are set, then there is no data to be read.

Comment: what library for socket programming do you use?

Comment: The part about `\0` is senseless when the data is binary, and TCP is not obliged to deliver you an entire packet at once.

Comment: @EJP edited my answer as a result. I though the TCP integrity guarantee obliged TCP to deliver the entire packet but realized you were right as I ran into that problem and wrote a circular buffer as a result.